# telegram bot deep linking with startgroup

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm currently working on to use the telegram bot's deep linking mechanism.
I'm focusing on to use the "startgroup" parameter to enable other users invite my bot to their group.

But after I tried to implement it, I faced on to a question that is "what kind of group is possible to invite this bot?".

Is there some kind of permission that I have to own in the group?
Is the group supposed to be a public group?
Is there any prerequisites that I have to make to invite my bot?

Answer (score 1):

reply_markup user:
https://t.me/xxxxxxx_bot?startgroup=soulu

exception:

```
let reply_markup = {
            "inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "AddThisBotFormMyGroup", "url": `https://t.me/ajtest02_bot?startgroup=soulu`}]]};

        let other = {chat_id:groupid,message_id:message_id,disable_web_page_preview:true,parse_mode:"html",reply_markup:JSON.stringify(reply_markup)};
        bot.editMessageText(t,other)
```